# Migrating from sql to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to transfer a database that I created with sql server with the information in mysqle. An example sql file is as follows
No connection to the database should be interrupted during this migration.
[SQL File](https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20211225yCjuxxuf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the length of the script, it would be best to you use an online converter. A good choice is sqlline (http://www.sqlines.com/online), which supports syntax conversions for a multitude of different database engines, including from SQL Server to MySQL.